# Can't enter the Group Policy Management

Tags: group-policy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrSe8.jpg)I wanted to edit some settings in group policy management but when I type "gpmc.msc" in run, it tells me than I have to log on with a domain user account, so how do I do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt1Vu.png)

I saw this in an article and wanted to do what he say because it solves my problem, so how can I?
"After doing more research, I ran across a KB article from Dell, Miracast/WiDi Problem After Connecting to a Domain. The article talks about a GPO setting that will prevent Miracast from working. The GPO setting is: Don’t allow WiFi Direct groups. I ran the gpresult command and reviewed the results in order to see if this was my issue.
In order to do the same, from the Run command line, open a cmd prompt.
Enter: gpresult /h:c:\gpo.html
Troubleshoot Miracast - Disabled
Here’s how you review the gpo.html file. Start with Settings | Policies | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Wireless Network (802.11) Policies | Network Filters, and then locate Prevent connection to adhoc networks. If this is set to Disabled then you will need to change your GPO settings! Below are the steps I took to update my GPO settings.
Update GPO Settings

Troubleshoot Miracast - Group Policy Management Editor
Open Group Policy Management Editor (you might need an Active Directory (AD) Administrator to do this for you) and locate the Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies node."
the full article: https://askgarth.com/blog/how-to-troubleshoot-miracast-when-using-windows-10/?sfw=pass1635441753

Comment: Is your computer joined to a domain? I'm assuming you need to change the local group policy and not the domain group policy. Try searching in your taskbar: Edit Group Policy or Local Group Policy

Comment: what is the different?

Comment: the domain group policy is for applying polices to users/groups/workstations in a domain, for example: you work at a company with multiple departments that need access to different folders, this is where you would use group policy.

Local group policy is for applying policies to the local user accounts and your local computer.

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: um... do you know how to do the steps in the article?

Comment: @Zanyar - So is your machine connected to an Active Directory domain?  [edit] your question to indicate if it is or isn't in clear terms.

Comment: is it necessary to change my computer settings? i don't know what is active directory domain.

Comment: @Zanyar - You will have to do the necessary research in order to answer that basic question about your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean? I just want to edit some settings.

Comment: I just want to know that if it is necessary to join a domain in order to change the group policy?

Comment: @Zanyar - You need to tell us by editing your question if the machine is connected to an Active Directory domain.  Without that information the question as it’s currently written (excluding all the commentary) cannot be answered

Comment: @Ramhound  I searched about that and found that my pc is not connected to an active directory domain, it is a member of a work group, but does this mean that i can't change my own pc settings?

Comment: If you are NOT connected to a Active Directory domain then you should be using the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) instead of the Group Policy Management Console (gpmc.msc)

Comment: @Ramhound  yes you are right but i can't find the setting in the tuorial in the local group policy

Comment: do they have the same settings? if not then how can I edit those settings? (that are missing from local group policy)

Comment: Have you looked? You are aware that Miracast isn’t supported by modern AMD nor Nvidia  display drivers, right? Unless you set the policy specifically it would be in a i nonconfigured state and be disabled…

Comment: I'm just trying to show my mobile not TV display on my laptop

Comment: how can I set the policy specifically?